# Browser stops receiving data when tty is active

Tags: linux, tty

I do listen to internet radio with linux gui browser. And I do work on tty.
The problem is that I can't do these things simultaneously.
When I do switch to tty, radio works for several seconds and then stops until switching back to the linux gui.
What сan cause this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you switch between X (graphics) and a virtual console with Ctrl-Alt-F1 etc.? If yes, only one virtual console can be active, and X runs on a virtual console. Easiest workaround is to use an `xterm` etc. instead of working on a virtual console.

Comment: xterm is not solution for me. I am working with framebuffer in fullscreen mode.

Comment: which browser? I am experiencing the same thing which Chromium.